can someone help me about the grammar されている
Hello I just want to confirm this sentence because it's confusing to me.
この電池は充電されている。
In an English book it's translated as " This battery is charged. "
Does this mean it is currently charging or it is already fully charged?
I always thought ている is a continuing expression so I've personally translate it as " This battery is being charged. " but if I am wrong then I hope someone can explain it to me.

Mandatory link for this kind of question: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/when-is-v%e3%81%a6%e3%81%84%e3%82%8b-the-continuation-of-action-and-when-is-it-the-continuation-of-state

I have read the link you posted but I just still couldn't properly understand the sentence on my post. It's like it is lacking expression compare to the samples on the link.
アイスが溶とけているよ、
アイスがぜんぶ溶とけている
Compare to these two I can understand the difference.
I hope there is an easier explanation for me to finally get why it is considered that the battery is already charged.

As explained in a related question suggested on comment, the expression ている has several distinct meanings according to the nature of the verb associated with it (and context).
I think 充電されている can express both of your options. This is because 充電される can plays a role as an “event verb” when depicting the entire period of being on charge, and also as a “change-in-state verb” when depicting the moment of the completion.
However, in reality, we often employ other expression like 充電中だ for the former meaning, so the latter interpretation seems more natural in absence of enough context.
